# Изменение стилей класса с помощью js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть класс

```
<div class="box> text </div>
```

И есть кнопка

```
<input type="button" value="Текст" onclick="document.getElementByClassName('box').style.background ='red'"/>
```

Не получается изменить фон div`a. Может я не правильно обращаюсь к классу?

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/1538

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, написано неправильно, ниже 2 рабочих варианта:

```html
<div class="box">text</div>
<hr />
<input type="button" value="Хочу красный" onclick="document.querySelector('.box').style.background ='red'" />

<input type="button" value="Хочу зелёный" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0].style.background ='green'" />
```

Comment: Жаль, что когда он добавит еще дивов с тем же классом - первый вариант не сработает для них всех)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, конечно всегда нужно предполагать все варианты, но если в вопросе это не подразумевается, то этого может никогда и не быть. Вы, например, тоже не учли вариант, что эти несколько блоков нужно будет красить в разные цвета и каждый своей кнопкой, а то красить все блоки в один цвет одной кнопкой это как-то непрактично :)

Comment: Просто, я думаю, не зря там установлен класс. Вот и всё) Красить вполне возможно в один цвет, почему нет?. Может это плитки для фотографий, а это будет их оформление)

Answer (score 6):

Во-первых: у вас не закрыта кавычка у `class="box`. Должно быть `class="box"`

Во-вторых: надо писать *getElement**S**ByClassName*, потому что по классу выбирается коллекция элементов.

В-третьих: так как это коллекция, массив, то значит надо обращаться к элементу коллекции и только ему устанавливать свойство:

```html
<div class="box"> text </div>
<input type="button" value="Текст" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0].style.background ='red'"/>
```

Для окраски всех элементов класса `.box` надо организовывать цикл, емнип

Примерно так:

```html
<div class="box"> text </div>
<div class="box"> text22 </div>
<div class="box"> text333 </div>
<input type="button" value="Текст" onclick="var x = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}"/>
```

---

А вообще лучше скрипт выносить из разметки, ибо это ужасно наблюдать

```js
document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("click", modifyBG, false);

function modifyBG() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> text </div>
<div class="box"> text222 </div>
<div class="box"> text33 </div>

<input type="button" value="Текст" id="test"/>
```

---

А еще стоит стили выносить в `css`, а в скрипте только присваивать нужные классы, идентификаторы и прочее

```js
document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("click", modifyFunc, false);

function modifyFunc() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].classList.add('my-style');
  }  
}
```

```css
.my-style {
  background: #ff0000;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> text </div>
<div class="box"> text222 </div>
<div class="box"> text33 </div>

<input type="button" value="Текст" id="test"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.box {
    background: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<input type="button" value="Текст" onclick="document.querySelector('.box').style.background='red'"/>
```